# getting an empty JSONObject from postman to jersey in POST method

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jersey

I am new to java Web development and i am currently using Jersey for REST. When i try to get parameters in POST method as JSONObject, i ended up with empty JSONObject. But i figured out an alterative way of using bean class and JAX-B mapping. The thing is, i know there is a way to directly get it as an JSONObject since i have used it previously i couldn't figure it out.

This the code i wanted to work

```
    @POST
    @Path("addstate")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addState(JSONObject newState) throws JSONException
    {
        
        System.out.println(newState);
        return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).entity(newState).build();
    }
```

but the output i get is,

`{}`

Comment: Chances are that you have a catchall route that is returning the empty `{}`. The reason is because your path is ambiguous. Try changing your path annotation to `("/addstate")` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You have a System.out.println() there. Does it ever reach that line and what does it log?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Jersey will automatically add the slash for you.

Comment: What providers are you using and have you done any configuration to them? JSONObject is not supported out of the box without further configuration of the Jackson provider. I personally would drop the use of JSONObject and switch over to using POJOs like you did with JAXB. POJOs are supported with JSON, if you have the correct provider. For the most part, you will be able to use the same POJO for both XML (JAXB) and JSON.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Hey paul thank you so much for the help, to answer your question, i have used jersey-media-json-jackson as providers and i haven't configured them. can you walk me through the configuration process because i have tried it setting them up in web.xml , but i couldnt achieve it

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake i have made is, i have added multiple providers for JSON. It is sufficient to uncomment the "jersey-media-json-binding" dependency while creating jersey projects using maven archetype to make use of JsonObject Class  and etc... for the project.

This dependency will be commented initially, just remove comments to it

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

To bind properties to Bean Class, there are annotaions that comes with the former package, that we can make use of.

Now i can use,

```
import jakarta.json.JsonObject;

...

Class MyResource
{

...

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JsonObject getJson(JsonObject obj)
    {
        System.out.println(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

by importing JsonObject from jakarta.json.JsonObject;

if you wish to use some other JSON provider, never forget to register them (unless it gets registered automatically).